# How does one get an instance of the .NET Android.Bluetooth.LE.ScanFilter class?

Tags: android, .net-core

In .NET, how does one instantiate or get an instance of Android.Bluetooth.LE.ScanFilter class? It doesn't seem to have any constructors, and in two hours of Googling I have failed to turn up any examples or even mentions of it other than the Microsoft doc class definition. But the class seems to be necessary for calling BluetoothLeScanner.StartScan with any filters on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I needed in a Java example, and translating the capitalization conventions this works in C#:

```
ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().SetServiceUuid(parcelUuid).Build();
```

Where the **Set...** calls are setting whichever filter properties are relevant to your case; in my case, obviously, I'm looking for a particular service UUID.